# Resources for Sound Synthesis & Design

Tags: sound, signal-processing, reference-request

Are there any resources for sound synthesis using Mathematica?

This page, [Mathematica: Audio Synthesis Software](https://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/analysis/content/AudioSynthesisSoftware.html), refers to other software packages, e.g. Max/MSP and Csound, for real-time synthesis.

However, I would like to use Mathematica's signal processing capabilities for analysing the sound effects of various filters, before I have to delve into some other package.

`Play` and `Sound` do not seem to have any real-time capability.

*Max/MSP features image*

[image]

**Edit**

The immediate stumbling block is the lack of real-time control when using `Play`, e.g.

```
EmitSound[Play[Sin[500 t^2], {t, 0, 10}]]
```

For instance, the played sound wave doesn't seem to be easily manipulated.

```
 Manipulate[EmitSound[Play[Sin[500 a t^2], {t, 0, 10}]], {a, 1, 4}]
```

Note. You may need to quit Mathematica to stop the above command.

If the emitted sound can be manipulated then filter effects could be applied in variable magnitudes.

Comment: Chris, I fear this question is too broad at the moment. Be happy to retract though if you make a good case ;-)

Comment: @Yves - a good place to start would be getting dynamic control of an emitted sound.  I have added an edit addressing this.

Comment: For the kind of control you seem to be seeking, you probably want to work at the level of the waveform (e.g., sing `SampledSoundList`) rather than trying to use higher level commands such as `Play`. But, you will not be able to get real time action from Mathematica as you can for instance in Max/MSP -- at best you will work off line, generate a sound and then play the sound.

Answer (score 3):

6 years later, I found that somebody asked the same I was asking myself an hour ago. Here is what I found to be possible in 2020:

```
freqinitial = 440;
freq = freqinitial;
stream = AudioStream[Function[t, Sin[2 Pi t freq]]];
Column@{Button[
   Dynamic[stream["Status"]],
   Switch[stream["Status"],
    "Playing", stream["Status"] = "Paused",
    "Paused" | "Stopped", stream["Status"] = "Playing"
    ]
   ],
  Slider[Dynamic[freq], {freqinitial, 2 freqinitial, 1}],
  Dynamic[freq]
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might check out [this WTC2020 talk by Leonardo Laguna Ruiz](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=488&v=3213).